Unable to install zeroc-ice package(building wheel) in python for omero-py
I have been trying to install omero-py but whatever I try it fails at building wheel for zeroc-ice. I have installed and uninstalled visual studio build tools multiple times but of no use.
Building wheels for collected packages: zeroc-ice
  Building wheel for zeroc-ice (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for zeroc-ice (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [203 lines of output]
      <string>:111: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
      WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only .-separated package names in setup.py
      running bdist_wheel

src/ice/cpp/include\IceUtil/Timer.h(105): error C2039: 'binary_function': is not a member of 'std'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\set(22): note: see declaration of 'std'
      src/ice/cpp/include\IceUtil/Timer.h(105): error C2504: 'binary_function': base class undefined
      src/ice/cpp/include\IceUtil/Timer.h(105): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.41.34120\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2 
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for zeroc-ice
Failed to build zeroc-ice

Here is my c_cpp_properties.json file.
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22621.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.41.34120/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

I tried different c++ versions but that didnt work. I even tried to make changes based on the errors, but no luck


c_cpp_properties.json is irrelevant to the build, that file is IntelliSense settings.



std::binary_function is deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17.



You might want to try a newer omero-py.


"trying to install" -- that is your goal and sure interesting as context info. What precisely did you do though? Please describe the exact steps taken! Without that, it's impossible to say where you went wrong. Also, make sure your environment is supported and that there are no existing bugs, so check the upstream documentation and bugtracker.
